# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when property set on custom class at initialization?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I have a simple Answer class that looks like this:

```
@interface Answer : NSObject {
  NSString *_text;
  NSNumber *_votes;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *votes;

+(id)initFromAnswerData:(NSSet *)data;
-(id)initWithText:(NSString *)answer;

@end
```

The implementation looks like this:

```
#import "Answer.h"
#import "AnswerData.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation Answer

@synthesize text = _text;
@synthesize votes = _votes;


-(id)initWithText:(NSString *)answer {
  if( (self=[super init])) {
    _text = answer;
    _votes = 0;
  }
  return self;
}


@end
```

If I create an array of Answers in a view controller using the `initWithText:` method I inevitably have EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors when I take an Answer in the array and try to find it's text value.

However if I initialize a new Answer, set the text value and then add it to the array I don't have this access issue.

So this causes problems down the line:

```
[arrayOfAnswers addObject:[[Answer alloc] initWithText:@"Hello"]];
```

But this doesn't:

```
Answer *newAnswer = [[Answer alloc] initWithText:nil];
newAnswer.text = @"Hello";
[arrayOfAnswers addObject:newAnswer];
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: NSNumber is a class. Use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]`

Comment: this may be dumb, but you are in fact allocated and initializing arrayOfAnsers, right? I would guess you are since you can successfully add an object, even if it's not the way you want to. Need to ask though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the attribute **_text** and **_votes** directly but not their setters.
So, you're not retaining the input parameter **answer** for the line

```
_text = answer;
```

You should either change to

```
_text = [answer retain];
```

or

```
self.text = answer;
```

Comment: I was having a very similar problem (using _ instead of self.) and this solved it for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you retaining the array that you put your `Answers` into? That would be my guess at what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

as you see , your 
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *text; // this property is retain.
so the setter method of this should be`- (void) setText:(NSString*)text{
[_text release];
 _text = text; 
[_text retain];`
so when you call newAnswer.text = @"hello" ,it works, newAnswer holds the text.
but in your initWithText, there's no retain symbol, so sucks.